# TFS 2017 - how to run a build with code coverage?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Hi I'm trying to run a build with code coverage, I am using Visual Stuido 2017 enterprise I have tried to enable the code coverage in VS but if i click on Edit build definition in team explorer it opens the build definition in TFS.

Comment: Have you chosen the Test task, and ticked "Code Coverage Enabled" in the build deifnition?

Comment: No i didnn't... I'm such a newbie... thanks anyway

Comment: Now when i run the test task it say `No Result found to publish`

Comment: Do you have tests being run in your Tests task? You can use wildcards to tell it to pick up all DLL's that have Test in the name.

Comment: Yea i do, how to use wildcards? (sorry for asking silly question but im new to this stuff)

Comment: Here's an example of the Test Assemblies I have set in one of the Testing tasks I have `$(build.sourcesDirectory)\Source\Tests\**\Release\*Test*.dll`

I have my solution structured in a Source folder, where Tests live inside in "Tests", inside in the Tests folder will be several solutions for each unit test project for each solution layer. The above pattern will pick up all DLL's where the name contains Test.

Comment: Ah, Okay i see ill try that now and ill get back to you Thank you

Comment: Ok it works Thanks boss

Comment: @ColinM Thanks for the sharing.You could move your solution from comment to the answer, which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: Code coverage is a wrong measurement without any benefits. Especially because it cannot calculate integration tests. Here is an article to help on that cause.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/before-you-feed-unit-test-beast-s-a-n-j-ay-mohan/?trackingId=5eIFIJGSBpnGuXMEz2PnwQ%3D%3D .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apologies for the delay in posting this as an answer.

As a prerequisite to using Code Coverage, the first thing to do is to install Visual Studio Enterprise on the build agent (Which you have already done). Following this, you must then update your builds to specify that Code Coverage is/should be enabled.

To enable code coverage, ensure you have included a Visual Studio Test task (or any equivalent which supports Coverage) in your build definition.

Once you have added the Test task, you'll want to configure this task and set your test assemblies, for this you can use an absolute path to point to a DLL file, or use wildcards like I do here

> $(build.sourcesDirectory)\Source\Tests**\Release*Test*.dll

This says that in my sources directory I have a folder called Source, and inside that is a Tests folder which contains all of my unit tests. Then in each Unit Tests folder I use a wildcard to say "any folder at all that contains a Release folder", look inside and take the DLL which has 'Test' in its name.

So now that the testing assemblies are gathered, you can tick the checkbox that says "Code Coverage Enabled", and you're good to go.

I will edit this post later today to include screenshots of my own personal VSTS builds.

Comment: Do you register a license for the Visual Studio Enterprise installation in any way or just install it? Or do we need it to be registered to one of our developers accounts for this to work?

Comment: When configuring the VS Instance on the server I've always used my MSDN Subscription to log in, and that has always allowed for code coverage to be published even when the 'logged session' expires.

Comment: Where is that screenshot?